# QA generation on sub sentences - NLP

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp, heuristics

My dataset is structured like this:

Product1 - Sentence1

Product2 - Sentence2

Product3 - Sentence3

.
.

etc

The sentences look like this:

Product1 - "We suggest that you wear this stylish piece with gold-toned drop earrings, churidar leggings and flats to complete an understated look."

A possible question to this can be - "Do we suggest that you wear this stylish piece with gold-toned drop earrings, churidar leggings and flats to complete an understated look?" - This is what i get using http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~ark/mheilman/questions/

### But, I want questions/answers like this:

Q: How can I get an understated look?

### A: You can try Product1 for an understated look.

Q: What can I wear with gold-toned drop earrings?

### A: You can wear Product1 with gold-toned drop earrings.

Q: What will give me a complete look with churidar leggings?

### A: Product1 will.

So, what i feel I want to do is - to create sub-question on the nouns/proNouns and adjectives in an semantically correct putting product in context.

Comment: what exactly is your question?

Comment: Hey, @MattiLyra, which part you want me to explain further ?

Comment: all of it, you haven't asked a question, you've outlined ways of solving a problem you have, but it is unclear what you expect the community to do for you, solve the problem for you, suggest APIs you could use or something else. Your _question_ should be explicit and concise - please have a look at the help center for guidelines on good questions http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @MattiLyra - I have precisely mentioned the output I want from the dataset I have. Which basically means a complete solution is appreciated - In case that is not possible any guidance on API's etc is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please have a look at [Google Cloud Natural Language API](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/)

It has '[Entity Recognition](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/analyzing-entities)' which might help your purpose. Here are the some [sample implementations.](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/docs/tutorials)

Comment: Let me try this if I can extract (relevant phrases - noun phrases) using these  API's. Will keep this thread updated.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to take a look for natural language services on the internet. Sometimes ago I had a similar problem and I solved it by using a service that you can finde [here](https://api.ai/).

On the website this is defined as:

> "API.AI is a natural language understanding platform that makes it
>   easy for developers (and non-developers) to design and integrate
>   intelligent and sophisticated conversational user interfaces into
>   mobile apps, web applications, devices, and bots."

The really cool thing about this is that you can train it with some

Comment: Yes, I know about this and have used it also. This is focussed more towards creating heuristic rules to identify the context with a word match. This is not generic to any context and hence can't be used in my case. Appreciate the help!